# Azure - VIP swap breaks outgoing connections?

Tags: azure, hotswap

I have a cloud service, and I see that during VIP swap - outgoing connections from the service outside are closed, while incoming connections are not impacted.

I did this experiment to test it:

- Connect to a VM in the production slot via RDP
- In that session - open a telnet connection to some external service
- perform VIP swap

After the swap I can see that the RDP session (incoming connection to the VM) was not disconnected, and I can see that indeed the external IP was changed (from the production slot IP to the staging slot IP), but the telnet session (which is outgoing connection) was disconnected.

Is there anything to do about this issue? Can we somehow maintain outgoing connections during swap?